# ldapsearch returns error when executing through java

Tags: java, ldap

I executed the ldapsearch command through java. See the below code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestMain
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        String ldspCmd ="ldapsearch -ZZ -h ldap-url.com -x -D cn=username,ou=webapps,ou=ec,o=uoa -w $(echo PassWord | base64 -di) -b ou=ec_users,dc=ec,dc=auckland,dc=ac,dc=nz \"(groupMembership=cn=bpmusers,ou=ec_group,dc=ec,dc=auckland,dc=ac,dc=nz)\"";
        String output = executeCommand(ldspCmd);

        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private static String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            BufferedReader errorReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            String erroLine = "";
            while ((erroLine = errorReader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(erroLine + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

But I get the error "ldapsearch: unable to parse debug value "i)"".

But when I execute the same command through command line it executes correctly and returns the records.

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help me to sort this?

Comment: *How* to you execute your command through Java? Please post an [mcve] - it's of course impossible to track your problem if you don't show what you are doing.

Comment: Command I posted is the exact thing I use. I removed the password and ldap url. What I am trying to do here is search for users who are in the group "bpmusers".

Comment: Post your Java code

Comment: It might help to use quotes with the password like `-w "$(echo PassWord | base64 -di)"`

Comment: @marabu No difference. Same result.

Comment: Obviously, your base64 options are interpreted as ldapsearch options by the command processor, so you should look that way. Also, don't forget about escaping the quotes properly.

Comment: @marabu, I didn't totally understand you....

Comment: I can tell from the error message you posted, that option `-di` is associated with ldapsearch instead of base64.

Comment: @marabu But when I execute the same command through the terminal, it works fine. So, I dont understand what it is the wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructs like `$(echo PassWord | base64 -di)` inside your argument list are interpreted and handled by your shell. And when you invoke a command from Java using `Runtime.exec`, you *are not* using a shell, you are passing the command directly to the operating system, so you don't get the benefit of the shell interpreting these constructs.

If you want those benefits, you need to explicitly invoke the shell.
Also, Java doesn't have the same complex logic to split arguments to a command that a shell does. Java just cuts the argument list at space characters.

So in your `executeCommand` method you have a line:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

You should change that to:

```
// Add shell invocation around the above command
String[] shellCommand = { "/bin/bash", "-c", command };

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCommand);
```

Comment: This works well. Thanks. Sorry for late response since I was busy with some other tasks.